# Border Second and Third Dropdown Only in React

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I wanted to put a border line on top the **second** and **third** dropdown only.
I still cant achieve it.
[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdown-styled-components-forked-yi5ho?file=/src/Dropdown.js)

```
const Select = styled.select`
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 0px;
  outline: 2px solid transparent;
  outline-offset: 2px;
  position: relative;
  appearance: none;
  background: inherit;
  padding-inline-start: 3rem;
  padding-inline-end: 2rem;
  height: 3.2rem;
  &:nth-child(1),
  :nth-child(3) {
    border: none;
  }
  border: 1px solid;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-color: #cecece;
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is, you're using `nth-child(1)` so, it'd apply on the select children but not on the select by itself.

The recommended modifier in this case would be apply directly on the element, in that case I'd say `nth-of-type`.

```css
&:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: red;
}
```

But the main problem with that one is ALL the elements have to be at the same level or the query has to be part of the grandparent.

So, in your code would work in this way:

```js
const Item = styled.div`
  margin: 0.2rem 0;

  &:nth-of-type(2) select,
  &:nth-of-type(3) select {
    background: blue;
  }
`;
```

Also, Taking advantage of `styled-components`. I included the index props. And use to include the border or not in your style. It's like:

```js
const Select = styled.select`
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 0px;
  outline: 2px solid transparent;
  outline-offset: 2px;
  position: relative;
  appearance: none;
  background: inherit;
  padding-inline-start: 3rem;
  padding-inline-end: 2rem;
  height: 3.2rem;
  border: ${props => props.index && [1, 2].includes(props.index) ? '1px solid #cecece' : 'none'};
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: none;
`;
```

I have forked your codepen, here you have both approaches working:

- With index
- **recommended** With grandparent query (this approach is using background)

https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdown-styled-components-forked-vpo6k?file=/src/index.js:285-366

Comment: I think you put the wrong link.

Comment: You're right edited, and here is: https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdown-styled-components-forked-vpo6k?file=/src/index.js:285-366

Comment: Hi @joseglego. Hmm I figuring it out, why the borders doesn't appear in my app.

Comment: Working now! Thanks!